# Jquery - error message disappears on form submit

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using [Jquery Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) for validating scripts on [my site](http://test.cuevu.com/contact.php). However, on submit the error message disappears. I have used the following script

> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> ```
>   var use_ajax=true;
>   var use_ajax2=true;
>   $.validationEngine.settings={};
>
>   $("#contact-form").validationEngine({ promptPosition : "bottomLeft",
>          success :  function(){use_ajax=true},
>           failure : function(){use_ajax=false;}
>          });
>
>
>   $("#contact-form").submit(function(e){
>           if(use_ajax)
>           {
>               $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');
>               $.post('mysubmitpage.php',$(this).serialize()+'&ajax=1',                    
>                   function(data){
>                       $("#contact-form").hide('slow').after('<h1>Thank you!</h1>');
>
>                       $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
>                   }
>
>               );
>           }
>           e.preventDefault();
>   }) });
> ```

Where am I going wrong? I want the error message to stay. How can I troubleshoot as I am fairly new to JQuery.

Comment: What happens if you replace `e.preventDefault()` with `return false`?

Comment: Either using e.preventDefault() or return false - the page isnt submitted - but it doesnt solve the problem of validation errors disappearing.

Comment: apparently I was trying to validate the textarea. On removal of the validation, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
if(status){
 your_function();
 }
}

function your_function(){
 //show message
     form.submit()
}
```